# jQuery only working on Squarespace page without # in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I am new to Squarespace and to jQuery.  I have implemented jQuery by it injecting into my header.

I am trying to get two paragraphs of text to be shown on click of H3.

```
<script type="text/javascript"     
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".read-more").click(function(){
$(".bio-more").slideToggle();
});
});
</script>

<div class="read-more">
<h3>Read More</h3>
<div class="bio-more">
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</div>

 .bio-more{
 display:none;
 }
```

It works when I view the page from the back end from a url that is 
my-accountsquarespace.com/whitney-oldenburg
(I don't seem to be able to access this page when logged out unfortunately)

But when I view this page:  http://gitanarosa.com/artist/#/whitney-oldenburg/
either logged in or out which is basically the same, but without some strange stretched out thumbnail at the top that Squarespace adds, it doesn't work.

Is it something wrong with my code?  I tried using an anchor element with "#" instead of H3, but that didn't make a difference?  Does it have anything to do with the # in the url?

Or is this some Squarespace specific problem?

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you use the selector as  `$(document).ready(function(){
$(".read-more h3").click(function(){
$(".bio-more").slideToggle();
});
});` , inteasd of pointing the selector to the parent container

Comment: why are you importing 2 JS files...? Isn;t it one is enough.

Comment: This works only from the backend as it did when pointing to the parent container.  As far the the 2 JS, I thought I might just play around with the different events, effects (what is the right word?).  Are there not different ones in jquery UI?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your page the block containing 'read-more' is injected dynamically when clicking on the thumbnails there. So normal jquery click handler wont work for dynamically created elements.
Try this,

```
$('body').on("click",".read-more h3",function(){
$(".bio-more").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work from the front or back end.  Do you mean the whole page is created dynamically?  Does that mean that I would need to edit the template itself maybe to add javascript to this page?  Is there a simple way you can explain the difference between your code and the two versions above?  Or a link to an article?  Thanks.

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj You say someone edited your answer.  It doesn't not work with their changes.  Can you please re-edit it back to your original answer?  Still haven't been able to get jQuery to work on dynamically created pages.